# Angular2 (with Typescript) compile with prepack (from Facebook)

Tags: facebook, angular, typescript

I have a project with Angular2 (Typescript) and I want to use the prepack (https://prepack.io/) on my bundle.js.min .

When run:

```
prepack bundle.min.js --out bundle.pre.js
```

The output is:

```
not an object
TypeError
at ParamDecorator (bundle.min.js:16:31440)
at bundle.min.js:3:23281
at bundle.min.js:3:23573
at call (native)
at s (bundle.min.js:2:547)
at bundle.min.js:2:606
at bundle.min.js:2:17723
at call (native)
at s (bundle.min.js:2:547)
at bundle.min.js:2:606
at bundle.min.js:2:4217
at call (native)
at s (bundle.min.js:2:547)
at bundle.min.js:2:606
at bundle.min.js:2:1316
at call (native)
at s (bundle.min.js:2:547)
at bundle.min.js:2:606
at bundle.min.js:3:11902
at call (native)
at s (bundle.min.js:2:547)
at e (bundle.min.js:2:722)
at bundle.min.js:2:303
at bundle.min.js:2:273
at bundle.min.js:2:4
at bundle.min.js:1:1
```

As the prepack is new it maybe be an prepack error but I thought that can be important to have and question about it here at the StackOverflow, I searched about and there's nothing about.

Hope anyone find the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If someone need the bundle code I could show it.

Comment: Are you generating a source map for bundle.min.js, as the error clearly states that you should?

Comment: I generated a source map for it and the problem continues "not an object"

Comment: Can you add github repo?

Comment: @HerlonAguiar did you find anything about this error ?

Comment: @Abdoutelb unfortantely no

Comment: @yurzui i can't add the github repo because it's a private project =/